# array data insertion in mysql and prevent duplicate in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, promise

Edit: I want to ask one more question, **can this be achievable from the javascript part only, wanted to know for learning purpose**

I'm inserting data in MySQL iterating data array in Nodejs.

```
 const customers = [{
    email : "rachel@friends.com" ,
    name : "rachel"
    },
   {
    email : "chandler@friends.com" ,
    name : "chandler"
    },
   {
    email : "chandler@friends.com" ,
    name : "friends"
    },
];
```

if the same email id arrive then I have to update the name of the existing  record to newly-arrived name
In above case
before 3rd record insertion

```
name     | email
Rachel   | rachel@friends.com
chandler | chandler@friends.com
```

after the 3rd index iteration records should look like this

```
    name     | email
    Rachel   | rachel@friends.com
    friends  | chandler@friends.com
```

I have  used promises async, await, and tried everything but it doesn't seem to be working as expected

```
async function insertCustomer(data) {
    
    data.forEach(async (person,index)=>{
        
        const promise1 = checkDuplicate(person.email);
        try{
            await Promise.resolve(promise1).then(async result=>{
                // console.log(result);
                if(result[0]['count'] == 0){
                   const promise2 = insert(person.email,person.name);
                   await Promise.resolve(promise2).then(result2=>{
                        // console.log(result2);
                        connection.commit();
                   });
                }else{
                   const promise2 = update(person.email,person.name);
                   await Promise.resolve(promise2).then( async result2=>{
                        // console.log(result2);
                        connection.commit();

                    });
                }
            });
             
             
            } catch(error){
            console.log(error)
            }
    console.log("finished");
});
}
```

Promises implementation

```
checkDuplicate = (email) =>{
    var sql = `SELECT count(*) as count from friends where email = '${email}'`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        connection.query(sql,  (error, results)=>{
            if(error){
                return reject(error);
            }
            return resolve(results);
        });
    });
};
insert = (email,name) =>{
    var sql = `INSERT INTO friends(name1,email) values('${name}','${email}')`;
    console.log(sql);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        connection.query(sql,  (error, results)=>{
            if(error){
                if(error['code'] = 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') console.log("duplicate occured herre");
                return reject(error);
            }
            return resolve(results);
        });
    });
};
update = (email,name) =>{
    
    var sql = `update  friends set name1 = '${name}' where email = '${email}'`;
    console.log(sql);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        connection.query(sql,  (error, results)=>{
            if(error){
                return reject(error);
            }
            return resolve(results);
        });
    });
};
```

The result from the above implementation

```
        name     | email
        Rachel   | rachel@friends.com
        chandler | chandler@friends.com
        friends  | chandler@friends.com
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the answer, yes this resolves the issue but is there any way that I can handle it from the coding part, Just wanted to know is it possible or not ? @msanford

Comment: use the insert on duplicate key.  The code change you're asking, will eliminate the need for the update clause.  just use the insert code and it handles both insert/duplicate cases.

Comment: @G-Force can this be achieved using javascript only?  Just wanted to know

Comment: yes it is JS only.  just need to change the call to the DB.